# Oracle SQL constraint to check data before allowing INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle

kinda new to SQL, so need some help here.
Firstly, please refer to the picture for my tables (BED table, WARD table, PATIENT table).

I am using **Oracle SQL Developer Version 19.4.0.354** as a learning tool.

=====================================================================

EDIT:
So i have changed the tables as like below:

BED(**BEDNO, BED_OCCUPIEDDATE**, WARDNO, PATIENTNO)

PATIENTS(**PATIENTNO**, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, GENDER, DATEOFBIRTH, MARITALSTATUS, PHONENO, REGISTEREDDATE, WAITINGLISTDATE, EXPECTEDSTAY, DATEWARDED, EXPECTEDLEAVE, DATELEFT)

WARD(**WARDNO**, WARDNAME, LOCATION, NUMBEROFBED, EXTNO)

BedNo is unique in the entire database. numbered from 1-240. Meaning WardA will have bedno 1-10, WardB might have bedno 11-20 and so on.

***How would i be able to allow allocation of patient to a ward only if there are bed available in the ward? Because currently, beds are not "tagged" to the ward if you refer to my ERD.***

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or table layouts. Instead, please include them as formatted text. Thanks.

Comment: I saw this same question on OTN a few days ago .... https://community.oracle.com/thread/4321559

Comment: Hi, thats me too. But probably this community is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Change the design a little.

First have the wards' table.

```
CREATE TABLE ward
             (wardno ...,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (wardno)
              ...);
```

Then in the beds' table reference the ward who attends this bed but not the patient that occupies it.

```
CREATE TABLE bed
             (bedno ...,
              wardno ...,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (bedno),
              FOREIGN KEY (wardno)
                          REFERENCES ward
                                     (wardno),
              ...);
```

In the patients' table reference the bed a patient occupies. A non existing bed cannot be referenced and without a bed a patient doesn't get a ward. By declaring the refereed bed unique, no more than one patient can occupy the same bed. If you don't want any patients without a bed, you can also declare the bed reference `NOT NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE patient
             (patientno ...,
              ...
              bedno ... NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (patientno),
              FOREIGN KEY (bedno)
                          REFERENCES bed
                                     (bedno),
              UNIQUE (bedno),
              ...);
```

And by the way, you shouldn't materialize the number of beds a ward attends, if that is what `ward.numberofbed` is supposed to store. Instead you should query that figure when needed. For convenience you can also use a view, so you don't need to repeat such a query.

Comment: Okay, yea i will probably try your suggestion. But initially, all bed numbers are not unique.  Meaning to say Ward A will have bed number 1-10. Ward B will have bed 1-12... and so on.